# Markdown in Apex?

Tags: apex, libraries

Has anyone built a [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) parser in Apex?  Looking to do something like this:

```
String raw = 'This is a *Markdown* string.  Large, multiline, has links & headings';
Markdown mdParser = new Markdown();
String parsed = mdParser.parse(raw);
System.debug(parsed);

// ==> 'This is a <em>Markdown</em> string.  Large, multiline, has links & headings'
```

Comment: I wonder if it might be better to use an API to do it for you rather than try to recreate everything in Apex. See https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/

Comment: I really wish Chatter could accept markdown formatting so code could be shared more easily.

Comment: An API could be one approach - or using a client-side javascript library.  With the API approach, I'd want to reduce call-outs by caching the processed version in a second long text area field, which is probably a best practice, anyway...

Comment: @DanielHoechst want to make your API suggestion an actual answer?

Comment: Did using client-side JavaScript not fit with where you needed the processing done? Seems like a good place to do the job if say you are just using Visualforce to present the HTML of a text area that contains markdown.

Comment: @KeithC my preference would be do prepare the final HTML on the server and then deliver the the client, so that there's less processing on the client side during the initial page render, but I'm using little enough Markdown for the current project that it might be OK this time around.

Comment: @Benj I've recently been using Angular where the approach is very much to convert the (compact) data into (verbose) HTML in the client. The client CPU has a lot more spare capacity than the server CPU, and JavaScript is now very fast in current browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using an API to parse your markdown and return back html. One service I found that looks like it would work is from Github: https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not currently any markdown support in apex, although it's conceivably possible to write one with enough effort.

As Daniel Hoechst suggested making a callout to an external markdown rendering service is very likely the easiest and fastest way of handling this.

On top of that it's very likely that any custom markdown rendering engine would have some compatibility bugs or security holes (depending on markdown flavor you can include raw HTML) unless you build an utterly amazing test suite.

Comment: Makes sense.  If only we could import Java libraries into Apex...

Answer (score 0):

While I was looking for the same thing I ran into this Github project: https://github.com/nilvon9wo/ApexMarkdownCompiler