# How would you get this project's Markdown language to work in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce

How would you get this https://github.com/lord/slate to work in Visualforce? The project Slate is:

> Slate is just Markdown — When you write docs with Slate, you're just
>   writing Markdown

The following article may be relevant to getting Markdown to work in Salesforce but I could not find any examples of how its actually implemented: [Markdown in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30593/markdown-in-apex)

I am assuming here that the dynamic aspects of the https://github.com/lord/slate project could be imported as a static resource and referenced in visualforce, but i have never worked with Markdown before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: you would not. Slate is more than just a simple browser rendition, so you can't just drop this thing into a page and have it work. However, you could use Slate to edit your documentation, then grab the *markdown* and render it in Visualforce or even Lightning.

Here's an example of using Markdown in Visualforce. This is not pretty, because I only spent about one minute typing this up, but it is functional.

---

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.markdownjs)}" />
    <script>
    function render() {
        var mark = Markdown(document.getElementById('input').value);
        mark.render(function(result) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
        });
    }
    </script>

    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
    <button onclick="render()">
        Preview
    </button>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
</apex:page>
```

---

My particular flavor of the Markdown parser was just a random one I pulled off of [GitHub](https://github.com/DmitryBochkarev/markdown/), written by a [Dmitry Bochkarev](https://github.com/DmitryBochkarev/).

Comment: thanks again @sfdcfox! turns out i really meant to ask how to deploy it somewhere that enforces authentication because github pages (by default) does not. You answered it how i asked though.  I learned that I can deploy its beauty to heroku (https://abangiya.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/slate-heroku/) as well as follow its instructions (https://github.com/lord/slate) to build the static files needed to deploy to my own server which i will attempt to do against Salesforce or perhaps any web host.